# App with phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 android crashes when a message is sent

Tags: android, crash, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap-push-plugin 2.0.0, and FCM. Android app crashes when notifications are sent. Here are the relevant codes.

**config.xml file is**

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="/google-services.json" />
</platform>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" source="npm" />   
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.0.0" source="npm">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="1:XXXXXXXX:android:YYYYYYY" />
</plugin>
```

**In Javascript code:**

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    registerForFCMPushNotifications();
    //... more code
}

function registerForFCMPushNotifications()
{
    var notificationObj = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXX",
            badge: "true",
            sound: "true",
            vibrate: "true",
            topics: ["all"],
            forceShow: "false"
        },
        ios: {
        },
        windows: {}
    });

    notificationObj.on('registration', function(data) {alert('Id='+data.registrationId);});
    notificationObj.on('notification', function(data) {alert("Got notification");});
    notificationObj.on('error', function(e) {alert( e.message );});
}
```

The Sender ID have been taken from FCM console itself.

Behavior observed:
If notification is sent when my app is running, then it gives a message that Unfortunately the app has stopped.

If notification is sent when app is not running, then no notification is showed on the phone.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from resource file /google-services.json so it becomes

```
<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
```

make sure google-services.json is in root directory

in config.xml

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

also include SENDER_ID in package.json (if using for other builds)

```
  "phonegap-plugin-push": {
    "SENDER_ID": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  }
```